# How to pass a requests session to pyqt5 QWebEnginePage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, pyqt5

I´m using the code below to get the source code of a website that uses JS. The problem is that there is a login area. I would like to pass a session from requests to QWebEnginePage so I don´t have to perform a login and can get the desired data. Has anyone an idea how to do this?

```
class Client(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self,url):
        global app
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ""
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print("Load Finished")

    def Callable(self,data):
        self.html = data
        self.app.quit()
```